# How Can I Implement Client-Side Caching for .glb Files Without Exposing Data in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, cryptography, react-three-fiber

## Question:

How can I implement client-side caching for my 3D models in Three.js without exposing or compromising the security of the data? Is there a way to include encryption or some other method that keeps my models protected while still reducing download latency?

## Details

I am working with 3D models in Three.js, and my server streams .glb files to the client through a protected GET route, using the [useGLTF(url)](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#usegltf) function. These files are not publicly stored, so they do not appear in the browser's 'Sources' tab, and unauthorized access to the GET route is prevented. I'd like to include a client-side cache to minimize latency when downloading these assets, but I'm concerned that this might expose my data to the client, and I want to avoid using public storage as it would directly expose my files.

### My Specific Concerns:

- **Security:** I don't want the raw data to be exposed.
- **Key Management:** Implementing client-side decryption (e.g., using Web Crypto API) introduces complexities related to key management.
- **Latency:** I need to reduce or avoid the latency of downloading the 3D assets.

## Ideas

I'm currently avoiding public storage by storing the files on my server and responding to GET requests with a data stream. I've considered encrypting the binary data of the .glb files before streaming to add an extra level of security. However, I'm wary of the complexities involved in client-side decryption and key management. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to implement client-side caching for my 3D models without compromising security or increasing complexity unnecessarily.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a conceptual question on how to use service workers like WorkBox with WASM to prevent direct exposure of 3d assets. PWA is new so resources are few on alternatives to storing 3d assets in public storage or unauthorized requests to API routes that would be streaming the 3d asset data.